# Codeigniter 3 dev Unable to load the requested class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in CI and now I'm trying to use CodeIgniter 3 to develop my site. I just only extract the framework and change only one think in config/autoload.php file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','input');
```

when I run the site, an error occur:

```
Unable to load the requested class: Input
```

When I tried it with CI version 2.2.0 stable, every thing is OK, no errors
Could some one explain why and help me to solve it?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is loaded by default...

Answer (score 4):

As of [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html) input library is loaded by default.

> This class (input) is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually.

Autoloading documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/autoloader.html

Comment: All classes inside system/core seem to be loaded automatically. Do you think It influences the speed of website (Because in CI 2.x, it does not load, and you can control it manually)

Comment: Not all of them (some are auto-loaded, some are not); I think you should not be worried about the speed at all, trivial change of speed.

Answer (score 4):

By default the library load from system/core folder in you CI. But the Input library is located on the core folder so you need to give relative path to the Input.php like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','../core/input');
```